# LocationProvider for Java SE

Tags: java, geolocation

Java ME has a class called LocationProvider (JSR 179) which finds out where the user currently is, using the best available sources (GPS, WIFI etc).

Is there a comparable library for Java SE?

For example Google Chrome browser has an API which finds the current location. Is there a way to access that info from Java SE?

Comment: You can probably play with IP location mapping

Comment: I know it can be done - question is whether somebody has already done it in a usable library

Answer (score 0):

At this stage there is no comparable location package (nor LocationProvider class) for Java SE. This functionality would certainly make sence particularly in the content of IP location or larger mobile computing devices.